# Convert .txt file into .cvs file using java?

Tags: java

I have a text file.

```
Date    Order ID    SKU Transaction type    Payment Type    Payment Detail  Amount  Quantity    Product Title

11-May-15   171-4579244-1779543 NT52-178    Refund  Amazon fees Commission  Rs. 49.32       Masha Women's Cotton Nighty NT52-178

11-May-15   171-4579244-1779543 NT52-178    Refund  Amazon fees Fixed closing fee   Rs. 11.24       Masha Women's Cotton Nighty NT52-178

11-May-15   171-4579244-1779543 NT52-178    Refund  Amazon fees Shipping holdback   Rs. 3.71        Masha Women's Cotton Nighty NT52-178

11-May-15   171-4579244-1779543 NT52-178    Refund  Product charges     Rs.
-399.00 1   Masha Women's Cotton Nighty NT52-178
```

I want to convert it into a CSV file.

I am using following code

```
   File file = new File("/Users/manish/Documents/New folder/report.txt");
       StringBuffer str = new StringBuffer();
       BufferedReader br = null;

        try
       {
            br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
            String text = null;

            // repeat until all lines is read
            while ((text = br.readLine()) != null)
            {
                    String splitarray[] = text.split("  ");
                    String Date = splitarray[0];
                    String Order_ID = splitarray[1]; // line 42
                    String sku = splitarray[2];
                    String Transaction_type = splitarray[3];
                    String Payment_type = splitarray[4];
                    String Payment_detail = splitarray[5];
                    String amount = splitarray[6];
                    String Quantity = splitarray[7];
                    String Product_title = splitarray[8];
                    System.out.println(Date+ " " + Order_ID);

            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally
        {
            try
            {
                if (br != null)
                {
                    br.close();
                }
            } catch (IOException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        // show file contents here
        System.out.println(str.toString());
```

but it gives error

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
>         at test_pract.TEST_pract.main(TEST_pract.java:42)
>       Java Result: 1

Comment: Check the number of elements in your `splitarray`. You are trying to access an element that is not there.

Comment: @Neftas I think problem is in String splitarray[] = text.split("  "); because i don't know how to split this txt file

Comment: Isn't it easier to simply replace the `  ` with `,`? Should be faster and less memory intensive. `text = text.replace("  ", ",")`; Unless of course you need to do some other conversion of data...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Problem are you empy lines, 
then your splitarray[] is empty and the use of splitarray[1] is not possible.

You can use an if statement to sort this out:

```
if(!text.equals("")) {
   splitarray[] ....
}
```

And you have another Problem: You split with 2 Whitespaces,
if you have 4 Whitespaces in your Text (and you have in your example) then you get an empty String in your Splitarray, because it is splitting between those 4 whitespaces. then you get different arrays per line.

you should eliminate these or use a better split argument like:

```
text.replace("    ", "  ")
```

or

```
text.split("    |  ")
```

the last one will try to split at 4 whitespaces or of not found at 2 whitespaces.

Comment: if this answer helps you, please accept is as solution